# using middlewares for specific namespaces in restify

Tags: node.js, namespaces, restify

I would like to use a middleware for checking users credentials only for some routes (those that start with `/user/`), but to my surprise `server.use` does not take a route as first argument and with `restify-namespace` `server.use` effect is still global.

Is there other way better than passing my auth middleware to all routes alongside the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm going to just use `server.use` and inside the middleware make the following route check:

```
if (req.url.indexOf('/user/') !== 0) {
    return next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `restify` doesn't seem to be like express, which support the `*` operator. Hence, What I would suggest is grouping the routes that you desire together and apply a `.use` before them.

That is:

```
server.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  // no magic here. server.use hasn't been called yet.
});

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // do your magic here
  if(some condition) {
    // magic worked!
    next(); // call to move on to the next middleware.
  } else {
    // crap magic failed return error perhaps?
    next(new Error('some error')); // to let the error handler handle it. 
  } 
});

server.get('/admin/', function(req, res, next) {
  // magic has to be performed prior to getting here!
});

server.get('/admin/users', function(req, res, next) {
  // magic has to be performed prior to getting here!
});
```

However, I would personally advocate the use of `express`, but choose whatever fits your need.